# Open a Command/PowerShell Prompt instance without default credentials

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I want to open a Command/PowerShell Prompt in Windows, without using the default credentials.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You don't want the console process to run as the current user?  Which user should it run as?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly your question, there's the `runas` command which runs a program with the specified user.
If you need `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` (System) privileges, `psexec -s` is what you need.
Another way (harder) would be creating a scheduled task with `schtasks` specifying the user with the switch `/ru`, running it and finally deleting it once the process is launched.